# BIC to test good fitting of data to a model

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, bic, scipy

I want to use the Bayesian Information Criterion in order to measure how well a gaussian and 0 order polynomial fit (using python), the one with the lowest BIC should then be the 'best fit' ?

My parameters are already known by using `scipy.curve_fit`, then all I should have to do is determine $\mathcal{L}$ the maximum of the likelihood function.

I had an answer previously on another forum but it quickly disappeared and someone told me that I could do the following but I do not understand how to get this formula (it work for both the polynomial and the gaussian):

```
# get log likelihood
logLgauss = -((n - 1) / 2) * np.log(np.sum((data - gauss_fit)**2))

# get log likelihood
logLhoriz = -((n - 1) / 2) * np.log(np.sum((data - line_fit)**2))

ngaussparams = 4  # number of Gaussian model parameters
bicgauss = ngaussparams * np.log(n) - 2 * logLgauss
nlineparams = 1  # number of parameters for the flat line
bicline = nlineparams * np.log(n) - 2 * logLhoriz
```